# Can I make multiple subplots in multiple Matlab figures within one loop?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

I want to export my data in two figures with four subplots each. But when I try to do this inside a loop it keeps printing only the second figure with four plots. And when I use `figure`, it prints eight figures with one plot each. Here is the part of code:

```
subplot(2,2,k);
plot(2.^[4:2:10], a, '-mo', 2.^[4:2:10], b, '-r+', 2.^[4:2:10], c, '-bx'  );
axis([2.^4, 2.^10, 0, max([max(a), max(b), max(c)])]);    
str = sprintf('Time for m1 = 2^%d',i);
title(str);
xlabel('n ')
ylabel('s') 

subplot(2,2,k);
plot(2.^[4:2:10],a1, '-mo', 2.^[4:2:10], b1, '-r+', 2.^[4:2:10], c1, '-bx'  );
axis([2.^4, 2.^10, 0, max([max(a1), max(b1), max(c1)])]);    
str = sprintf('Time for m1 = 2^%d',i);
title(str);
xlabel('n ')
ylabel('M')
```

Comment: Show the export part in your code. In which part do you do the exporting exactly? Also include `figure` and the essential part of the loop

Comment: Where is your loop? Maybe you could figure this out or get a bit further by creating a little demo that actually runs to illustrating what your code is doing.

Comment: have a look at my last edit, it's a complete general solution now. you can use it for every number of plots per figure.

Comment: when im trying to run this one 
Error using figure
Requested figure handle in use by another object

i already have a loop for making calculation and in the end i want two figures with 4 plot each to be printed
.for example 
for i=1:1:4  
 %calculations
      
figure1..........
figure2..........
end

Comment: have you considered the very last edit I made, there was little mistake. Now its working perfectly on my machine. Be aware that you shouldn't have any other figure(1 ... 8) before. Or add an offset `h+8` or something. Well I just gave you some ideas. I mean you're not giving us any information. So either be more specific or try to modify my example for your case, it should be easy.

Comment: the thing is that i  want 2 figures with 4 subplots each and in each sublot i need three curves so i cant have a loop ....i have to run all the programma and somehow save each sublplot and then add them in a figure is there any way to do this ?

Comment: thank you for your help ,i think i got it because i wanted 2 figures i just set an offset for the second figure.So when i run it makes the first figure with first subplot and then the second figure with the first subplot ,next goes back to the first figure again and makes the second subplot and etc...

Comment: yes, you just need introduce another index variable within your loop which distributes your curves into the right plots. Feel free to accept the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: ofcourse i didnt know i can accept the answer thanks again for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your loop needs to look somehow like this:

```
x = 1:2;
y = x;

f = 2;  %number of figures
c = 2;  %number of plots per column per figure
r = 2;  %number of plots per row per figure
n = repmat(cumsum(ones(1,r*c)),1,f);  %index for subplots
h = ceil( (1:f*r*c)/(r*c) ); %index of figures

for ii=1:f*r*c

   % calculations

   % plot specifier
   figure( h(ii) )
   subplot( r,c,n(ii) )

   % plot
   plot(x,y)

   % your plot properties
end
```

it gives you a `figure(1)` with 2x2 subplots and a `figure(2)` with 2x2 subplots

and for example

```
f = 3;  %number figures
c = 3;  %number of columns per figure
r = 4;  %number of rows per figure
```

would give you 3 figures with 3x4 plots each and so on...

---

If the order in which the plots appear matters, you can change the way `h` and `n` are created. These are just examples. Basically they are just vectors relating your index `ii` with the appearance order.